# The type 'obj' is not an interface type

Tags: f#

I have an interface, in **IAnimal.fs**,

```
namespace Kingdom
type IAnimal =
    abstract member Eat : Food -> unit
```

and another interface that successfully inherits it, in **IMammal.fs**.

```
namespace Kingdom
type IMammal =
    inherit IAnimal
```

But, when I try to inherit it again I get an exception (**IBird.fs**)

```
namespace Kingdom
type IBird =
    inherit IAnimal
```

The exceptions are

> The type 'obj' is not an interface type

and

> The type 'IAnimal' is not defined

and `IAnimal` har a red line under it in **IBird.fs**.

I've tried copy/paste the definition of `IMammal` and change `IMammal` to `IBird` but I still get the same error. Also tried restarting Visual Studio.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure your files are in the correct order in your project. A file can only reference types and values defined in earlier fields. So in this case `IMammal.fs` and `IBird.fs` must come after `IAnimal.fs`

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox that's the answer. Thought the order of the files was a bit too strange to be a-z...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure your files are in the correct order in your project. A file can only reference types and values defined in earlier fields. So in this case `IMammal.fs` and `IBird.fs` must come after `IAnimal.fs`.
>
> - [TheQuickBrownFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253533/the-type-obj-is-not-an-interface-type#comment85510994_49253533)